# C program to make a meaningful word from jumble words

Tags: c

I want to make a C program to arrange a jumble word into meaningful English word.There is a file "dictionary.txt" which contains lots of jumbled words. So, i have to write a program which read the jumble word from this file and convert it into a meaningful word.
For example:-
dictionary.txt file exits a "epemaxl" word
when we provide this input, the output should come "example".

I have searched alot over internet but didnot get a suitable example according to this.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i know these guys are gonna hate you for not posting your attempt .. but having said that  .. its actually a really interesting problem. My guess would be that you would have to have another text file ( like a proper dictionary ) to compare unjumbled words to

Comment: Is this an offline-only program? One approach is to try different permutations and check on a site (dictionary.com ?) to see if its a real word.

Comment: @chronodekar If it's online, there probably is an anagram webiste/service they could use.

Comment: Why was this put on hold ? This is the problem with this site. Once in a while someone asks a really interesting question and it gets put on hold.

Comment: Is there any source to get this full English word's file..or i've to create by myself...

Answer (score 6):

One strategy can be to calculate the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and select the word that has the closest levenshtein distance to your jumble word.

Comment: which implies that you need "another dictionary file which contains every word in the English language."

Comment: ...which is a simple thing to obtain

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux (say Debian or Ubuntu, can't tell about the rest of flavors), you could skip the making of real dictionary and just check with `/usr/share/dict/` wordlist.